# Vertical scaling of azure kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-vm-scale-set

I am unable to scale vertical my AKS cluster.
Currently, I have 3 nodes in my cluster with 2 core and 8 ram, I am trying to upgrade it with 16 code and 64 RAM, how do I do it?
I tried scaling the VM scale set, on Azure portal it shows it is scaled but when I do "kubectl get nodes -o wide" it still shows the old version.

Any leads will be helpful.
Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 3):

Vertical scaling or changing the node pool VM size is not supported.  You need to create a new node pool and schedule your pods on the new nodes.

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1556#issuecomment-615390245

> this UX issues is due to how the VMSS is managed by AKS. Since AKS is
> a managed service, we don't support operations done outside of the AKS
> API to the infrastructure resources. In this example you are using the
> VMSS portal to resize, which uses VMSS APIs to resize the resource and
> as a result has unexpected changes.
>
> AKS nodepools don't support resize in place, so the supported way to
> do this is to create a new nodepool with a new target and delete the
> previous one. This needs to be done through the AKS portal UX. This
> maintains the goal state of the AKS node pool, as at the moment the
> portal is showing the VMSize AKS knows you have because that is what
> was originally requested.

Comment: Thank you, we went ahead and created new Nodepool